# ImportError: cannot import name 'AppLayout' from 'ipywidgets'

Tags: python-3.x, ipywidgets

While importing `AppLayout` I'm getting the following error. I am using Jupyter and have installed `ipywidgets`. The same error is being raised when importing `GridspecLayout`. Can anyone help me with this?

All other imports from `ipywidgets` are working properly, atleast the ones I have imported.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'AppLayout' from 'ipywidgets' (C:\Appl\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\__init__.py)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you have the latest version of ipywidgets with `help(ipywidgets)`. 7.5.2 is required for this (https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/docs/source/changelog.md).

Comment: Yes, Thanks! It is the problem. How should it be updated? Or does it need to be reinstalled? Using just `pip install ipywidgets` did not help

Comment: FYI the ipywidgets gitter channel is quite useful for usage questions, and probably more responsive. https://gitter.im/jupyter-widgets/Lobby

Comment: `pip install -U ipywidgets` to upgrade.